# netbeans-8.1 // add tomcat8 server // CATALINA_HOME/conf/server.xml // wrong path

Tags: netbeans, tomcat, lubuntu

i'm trying to add tomcat8 server to netbeans 8.1 ide,

when specifying server location (catalina home) I provide ***/usr/share/tomcat8/*** but the program searches for the server.xml file into a ***/conf*** folder that doesn't exists.

the program returns this error message:
**The <
CATALINA_HOME>/conf/server.xml can't be read.**

in my instalation that file was stored into ***/etc/tomcat8*** folder,

but when i try to specify this path as server location i get the folowing error message: **The specified Server Location (Catalina Home) folder is not valid.**

how can i solve this issue?

thank you in advance.

Comment: To people getting here from Google: If you're using Tomcat 9, you'll need to upgrade to Netbeans 8.2.

Answer (score 1):

What I did was create the /conf folder and copy the server.xml file manually.